# Cointegration Test with Trend

Tags: r, time-series, trend

I have a data frame (df) with two variables where having already found out my order requires 5 lags I then tested the mean vector of the differenced series to see if I needed to consider (i) intercept (ii) no intercept and (iii) intercept and a time trend.

```
adfTest(df[,1], lags = 5, type = "c") # p-value 0.94
adfTest(df[,1], lags = 5, type = "nc") # p-value 0.91 
adfTest(df[,1], lags = 5, type = "ct") # p-value 0.04
adfTest(df[,2], lags = 5, type = "c") # p-value 0.96
adfTest(df[,2], lags = 5, type = "nc") # p-value 0.19
adfTest(df[,2], lags = 5, type = "ct") # p-value 0.74
```

(1) From the above p-values I can see that for my first series I should use an intercept and a time trend, but this is not the case for my second series. **Is this an issue?** (When I then used ca.jo test I found the presence of cointegration when I included an intercept and trend, but when I did not include a trend cointegration was then unsuccessful.)

I then conducted an eigenvalue cointegration test with trend:

```
cointest <- ca.jo(cointest, K = 5, type = "eigen", ecdet = "trend", spec = "transitory")
```

Where the critical values for r=0 resulted in rejecting the null of no cointegration.

This gave me the linear combination coefficients of:

1. Series 1 = 1
2. Series 2 = 0.1418577
3. Trend = - 15.7603490

(2) **How do I form a linear combination of these series?** I attempted the below code but I do not think it is correct.

```
s = 1.000*df$df[,1]+ 0.1418577*df$df[,2] - 15.760349**as.numeric(rownames(df)) # so the trend will decrease by 15.7 for each row
plot(s, type="l")
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johansen_test)

> The null hypothesis for the "maximum eigenvalue" test is as for the trace test but the alternative is r=r*+1 and, again, testing proceeds sequentially for r*=1,2,etc., with the first non-rejection used as an estimator for r.

So if you can´t reject the H0 for r=0 then there should be no cointegration relationship.

**Update**
I can´t give you a full answer but maybe my first thoughts:

It seems as df[,1] is trend stationary. Therefore I´m **not sure** if this timeseries is I(1) and fulfills the "conditions" of a VECM. If not it´s getting even more complicated. See [Peseran 2001](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/jae.616)

Maybe it is a good idea to check the stationarity with other tests aswell to be on the safe side. (PP-Test, KPSS, etc)

Also you could use the second test of `ca.jo` `type="trace`.

Depending your specific "trend" question I´m not sure and would also be interested in an answer ;)

Comment: Thanks - but using this link [https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Johansen-Test-for-Cointegrating-Time-Series-Analysis-in-R] I concluded that if my test statistic is greater than the critical value for r=0, then I reject the null of no cointegration.
 **The first hypothesis, r=0, tests for the presence of cointegration. It is clear that since the test statistic exceeds the 1% level significantly (8161.48>37.22) that we have strong evidence to reject the null hypothesis of no cointegration.**

https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Johansen-Test-for-Cointegrating-Time-Series-Analysis-in-R

Comment: You are absolute right. My quote is right but my conclusion ist absolute wrong. Maybe it was to hot here. Excuse me.

Comment: No problem. Are you able to comment on anything else from my questions? As I am quite stuck here...

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately using 'type="trace"' yields the exact same results. And I am still getting non-stationarity when I try these other tests. 
I am curious about the trend question too - I cannot see any similar examples online unfortunately. My latest edit to the question where I use 'rownames(df)' is a guess, but I believe it is intuitive...